# Position element to CGRect with Safe Area

Tags: swift, ios10, ios11, safearealayoutguide

I´m declaring a button:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: ?, y: ?, width: 50, height: 50))
```

But I´m note sure how to set `x` and `y` relative to the Safe Area so that it works good on both `>= iOS 11` and `<= iOS 10`.

I tried to use `self.view.safeAreaInsets` but it returns 0.0 for some reason. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: First of all you should use autoloayout if possible. In which place are putting this code, maybe it's to early? try in other places like viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I´m setting the button in viewDidAppear

Comment: I wonder if - because you are *not* using auto layout - you'll run into issues with the answer supplied by @Adis. An example.... Let's say `viewDidAppear` executes in portrait. You'll get a "Y" value that takes into account the notch, but your "X" value won't. Now, rotate counter-clockwise, or move the notch to the left. I'm pretty sure your button will be obscured by the notch. It might be a good idea to test this out before coding more.

Comment: @dfd, my app is only Portrait, would it still be an issue?

Comment: Probably not, but keep in mind that "notch". Portrait only means it can be on the bottom too.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 11:

`self.view.safeAreaInsets` will be zero if you call it on `viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc`

It should have the value if you call it on `viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 2):

I have same question when make animations.

Finally solved question, idea:create a frame equal safeArea frame.

(Device Orientaion only Left and Right)

```
CGRect safeAreaFrame;

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UIEdgeInsets safeAreaInsets = self.view.safeAreaInsets;
    safeAreaFrame = CGRectMake(safeAreaInsets.left,
                               safeAreaInsets.top,
                               self.view.frame.size.width - safeAreaInsets.left - safeAreaInsets.right,
                               self.view.frame.size.height - safeAreaInsets.top - safeAreaInsets.bottom);
} else {

    safeAreaFrame = self.view.frame;
}
```

then you have safe area frame use, for example:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:safeAreaFrame];
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Note: The safe area insets return (0, 0, 0, 0) in viewDidLoad,
hence they are set later than viewDidLoad,
put into viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange or viewDidAppear. 
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This would be far easier if you used autolayout and constraints, but you can get the margins of the safe area this way:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let topMargin =  window.safeAreaInsets.top
        let leftMargin =  window.safeAreaInsets.left
    }
}
```